# Intermittently getting HTTP 500 server errors while browsing the Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, timeout, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, http-status-code-500

We have enabled out-of-box Azure easy Authentication/Authorization for Azure web app using Azure AD and we have observed that the callback to authenticate the user after the user has logged in causes timeout intermittently.
**Exact Error** : "500 - The request timed out.
The web server failed to respond within the specified time."

[image: Check screenshot of Network Activity]

Note: We have a ASP.net **website** solution deployed to Azure. If the same user opens the site in a different browser at the same time then user will not face timeout issue.

Comment: What is your question? Is it why are you getting *Error 500*? Those errors some times are due to an intermittent or bad network connectivity (poor signal, low bandwidth, saturated network, bad connections...)

Comment: and in your main page of app ,do you have some codes which may start long time task ?

Comment: @GrayCygnus My question is why i m getting the error and how I can solve it? It seems the issue is related to ASP.NET_SessionID cookie, which is conflicting with AD cookie AppServiceAuthSession. Whenever we delete the ASP.NET_SessionID cookie manually and a call is made again we don't experience timeout again. Not able to exactly figure out how but when the site is idle for some time and users hits refresh, the session cookie is causing conflicting and we are not able to load the site and face the 500 - request time out error,

Comment: @Nan Yu - MSFT we don't have any long running operations.

Comment: What is your azure app service Always On setting ? If it is off ,try to turn on and test it .